# How do I declare a variable similar to the way ng-repeat does, but for a single object?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, html

I use ng-repeat to re-use a partial html class, as shown below. This works perfectly, because of Angular magic.

Parent Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
    @Html.Partial("_ItemViewer")
</div>
```

Relevant portion of Partial Html "_ItemViewer":

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description"
    ng-model="item.description"></textarea>
```

I can refer to "item" in the partial and it'll bind properly. That's precisely the behavior I want, but on a single object, without using ng-repeat.

My controller, "vm", has two separate properties, "A" and "B". They are the same kind of object. They may not always be, but they, for the time being, are. Which is why they share the same Partial Html form.

For instance:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>ItemA</legend>
    @Html.Partial("_SingleItem")
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>ItemB</legend>
    @Html.Partial("_SingleItem")
</fieldset>
```

I want to be able to refer to them as a variable, as is done in ng-repeat. 
Instead, I'd have to specify the model in the partial, "_SingleItem", like so:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" 
    ng-model="vm.itemA.name">
```

This ruins the re-use of the partial. What I need is to be able to do as shown below:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" 
    ng-model="item.name">
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: You can create a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a custom directive which will alias the desired value under a specified name, like this:

```
app.directive('myValue', function () {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //attach the value to the scope under an alias
            //just like ng-repeat does
            scope[attrs.newName] = scope.$eval(attrs.myValue);  
        }
    };
 });
```

And then in the template just wrap the partial in this directive:

```
<div my-value="vm.itemA" new-name="item">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" 
      ng-model="item.name">
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Just gave it a run and it seems to be working perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to create an isolated alias per fieldset group without a directive, you could use ng-repeat and filter to the precise item you want in your collection.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>ItemA</legend>
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter:{id: 1}:true | limitTo:1>
        @Html.Partial("_SingleItem")
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>ItemB</legend>
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter:{id: 2}:true | limitTo:1>
        @Html.Partial("_SingleItem")
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: That'd work if they were in a list, but I really do need them in separate properties. However, that's useful to know for other things anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Patching this on the client-side is both cumbersome and unnecessary.

Your `@HTML.Partial` *is not*, in fact, "the same partial" since it's clearly different, because it has a different `ng-model` attribute.

So, instead of backward patching it on the client, just pass a parameter to generate the proper HTML on the server. And if, and when, your partials become different, you won't have to change the client:

```
@Html.Partial("_ItemViewer", new {ngModel = "vm.itemA.name"})
```

Comment: How would I use that in the partial? That is to say, in my "_ItemViewer" html, how would I reference the ngModel that is being passed in, as per your example?